# Dockerfile placeholders not replaced during build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Using Docker for Windows, Community version 17.06.0-ce-win19 (12801), Windows 10

Dockerfile

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
ARG APP_NAME=client-default
RUN mkdir -p /client/
ADD build/libs/$APP_NAME.jar /client/$APP_NAME.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/client/$APP_NAME.jar"]
```

Running

```
docker build --build-arg APP_NAME=client-1 -t test/client-1 .
```

Placeholders not replaced after build (tried *${APP_NAME}*, *%APP_NAME%*)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) and [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) are [not replaced by Docker in an `ENTRYPOINT` or a `CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement) *when you use the EXEC form inside `[]`*. If the `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` use the shell form (string, not an array) the shell will be able to do the variable substitution for you.

`ARG` and `ENV` variables will be available in `RUN` commands in the container as environment variables.

Docker will also replace `$VARIABLES` in the `Dockerfile` in the following instructions:

- ADD
- COPY
- ENV
- EXPOSE
- FROM
- LABEL
- STOPSIGNAL
- USER
- VOLUME
- WORKDIR

Only `ENV` variables will become available in a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`, only in the environment of the running container:

Using `ARG`

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
ARG APP_NAME=client-default
ENV APP_NAME=$APP_NAME
RUN mkdir -p /client/
ADD build/libs/$APP_NAME.jar /client/$APP_NAME.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java -jar /client/$APP_NAME.jar"]
```

or with only `ENV`

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
ENV APP_NAME=client-default
RUN mkdir -p /client/
ADD build/libs/$APP_NAME.jar /client/$APP_NAME.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java -jar /client/$APP_NAME.jar"]
```

Comment: I hoped there was a way to replace somekind of placeholders in the ADD directive a.k.a during image build. Command docker build --build-arg app_name=client -t test/client .  doesnt work.

Comment: Is there another way to dynamically add an already built .jar file to an image, without knowing the .jar name infront?

Comment: `ARG` and `ENV` vars should work as you have used them in an  `ADD`

Answer (score -3):

**ARG** is only available during the build of a Docker image (RUN etc), not after the image is created and containers are started from it **(ENTRYPOINT OR CMD)**

ARG variable doesn't get substituted in Dockerfile. ARG IS really an environment variable. During the build, docker "runs" the container using ARG variables as environment variables. Easy to prove (you can test it): Try `RUN printenv` on your Dockerfile and you'll see the ARG as environment variable

So, you've got two problems:

**First:**

The Steps in console DOESN'T substitute the ARG variable. So, your jar is really in the container, your line:

```
ADD build/libs/$APP_NAME.jar /client/$APP_NAME.jar
```

it's working. Try it.

**Second:**

Entrypoint is for the running container, not for the image, so you need to put your *ARG* into an *ENV* variable, and not to use the exec form. If your use the exec form of ENTRYPOINT does not invoke a command shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. If you want shell processing then either use the shell form or execute a shell directly, for example:

```
ENTRYPOINT cat ${APP_NAME_RUN}
```

So, try this **working example**:

```
FROM ubuntu
ARG APP_NAME=client
RUN mkdir -p /client/
ADD ./$APP_NAME.txt /client/$APP_NAME.txt
ENV APP_NAME_RUN="/client/${APP_NAME}.txt"
RUN echo $APP_NAME_RUN
ENTRYPOINT cat ${APP_NAME_RUN}
```

Comment: ARG is seperate to ENV which sets an environment variable.

Comment: No. Both are environment variables.  ARG is an environment variable that is uses only in build time. ENV is an environment variable persisted when running a container.

Comment: ARG is just an environment variable used in build time. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg

Comment: Not exactly. ARG variable doesn't get substituted in Dockerfile. ARG IS really an environment variable. During the build, docker "runs" the container using ARG variables as environment variables. **Easy to prove** (you can test it): Try "RUN printenv" on your Dockerfile and you'll see the ARG as environment variable.

Comment: Cool, I didn't realise docker used environment variables as the interface for ARGs in RUN! Deleted that comment.  But `ARG` does get substituted for that list of commands as well. `ARG test=what`  `ADD $test other`  `docker run IMAGE cat /other` works too, and doesn't use env vars there, as you highlighted those commands don't have an environment

Answer (score -3):

Environment variables in Dockerfile are declared with the `ENV` statement.

In your case:

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
ENV APP_NAME client-default
RUN mkdir -p /client/
ADD build/libs/${APP_NAME}.jar /client/${APP_NAME}.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/client/${APP_NAME}.jar"]
```

Comment: You may find my [Reference here](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement)