# Docker container not using ENV variables

Tags: java, docker, heap-memory, amazon-ecs, docker-container

SO I am trying to change the JVM heap memory percentage
I have added these two lines in my Dockerfile

```
ENV JAVA_OPTS="--XX:MinRAMPercentage=50.0 --XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0"
CMD ["--spring.profiles.active=${profile}","${JAVA_OPTS}"]
```

But when I check this command:`(java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -E "UseContainerSupport | InitialRAMPercentage | MaxRAMPercentage | MinRAMPercentage")` on my docker container, it shows default values of the above parameter: [image]

Comment: Can you show the `docker run` command you use?

Comment: I have pushed the docker image to ECR and created a task definition which is pulling this image and running it in ECS so I am not running the container manually

Comment: Can you run the image locally, to check if the image itself is fine? If locally all is fine, then somewhere in ECR-world the same env-var will be set.

Comment: something in the startup script / entrypoint / run command must actively include `JAVA_OPTS`, that's not a builtin Java feature, just a common environment variable name used in many startup scripts, `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` https://stackoverflow.com/a/58355963/995891 on the other hand seems to be a property picked up by the jvm by itself. And I think `"${JAVA_OPTS}"` isn't evaluated because https://stackoverflow.com/a/47573374/995891

Comment: What does your ENTRYPOINT look like? You need a shell to be able to do environment variable substitution.

Comment: if you use spring boot, there's a nice guide on how to build docker images here: https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker in the end even ones that configure jvm parameters dynamically (via https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack-memory-calculator)

Comment: @zapl This link helped me resolve the issue I added ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS "-XX:MinRAMPercentage=50.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0" and it worked.

Comment: Have you  checked if your `spring.profiles.active` works? You can use `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` in env as well in case that has the same problem

Comment: @zapl  it is working, can you pls post your comment as answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 3):

No environment variable expansion or other processing is done on [exec form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) `CMD` (or `ENTRYPOINT` or `RUN`).  Your application is getting invoked with literally the strings `--spring.profiles.active=${profile}` and `${JAVA_OPTS}`, and you will see these including the `${...}` markers in your Java program's `main()` function.

Docker's normal assumption here is that any expansion like this will be done in a shell, and [shell form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example) `CMD` will wrap its string in `/bin/sh -c '...'` so this happens.  However, this setup isn't compatible with splitting `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`: due to the mechanics of [how the two parts are combined](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) neither part can be wrapped in a shell if you're using the "container as command" pattern where the `CMD` is just an argument list.

The easiest way to handle this is to ignore `ENTRYPOINT` entirely; put all of the command and arguments into `CMD`; and use the shell form rather than the exec form.

```bash
ENV JAVA_OPTS="--XX:MinRAMPercentage=50.0 --XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0"
# no ENTRYPOINT; shell form of CMD
CMD java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar /app/app.jar --spring.profiles.default=${profile}
```

If you `docker run` a temporary debugging container on this image, it will see the environment variable but the command you provide will replace the image's `CMD`.

```bash
docker run --rm your-image \
  /bin/sh -c 'echo $JAVA_OPTS'
# prints the environment setting
```

Correspondingly if you run a separate `java`, it won't see the options that are only provided in the image's `CMD`.  (Similarly try running `java -XX:MaxRamPercentage=80.0` in one terminal window, and `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` with no other options in another window, and the second invocation won't see the JVM options from the first JVM; the same mechanics apply to Docker containers.)